Can "plucking up" be used together?
Question: Someone saw him plucking a mango. (Change the voice)
What can be the correct answer from the two options below?
A) He was seen plucking up a mango by someone.
Or
B) He was seen by someone plucking a mango.
I felt like plucking already conveys the meaning and doesn't need "up" as a preposition added to it.
But I was told that option A was correct rather than B and I wanted to know if there are any rules of grammar which can show why one is right and the other is wrong.

Who told you that A was the answer? To me the only sensible answer is B, and A is a bad answer intended to diagnose the lazy or inattentive students. How can you pluck up a mango when they grow on trees? To pluck a fruit is to remove it from where it grows.

I attended an administrative exam where English grammar was a part of it, the answer key had "plucking up" as the answer and I chose option b which had "plucking" in it, which as you said seemed most sensible and the only was I can challenge the answer is by citing a English grammar book as a reference.

The correct expression here is pluck, not pluck up. The basic meaning of the word is to separate something attached to something else. So we pluck fruit from a tree. We pluck feathers from a dead bird. And (a passion of mine!) we pluck a guitar string by resting our finger on the string and then pulling it away to make the sound.
There is however a particular expression using the phrase pluck up. We talk metaphorically about plucking up courage to do something hard. Today I finally plucked up the courage to talk to my neighbour about the rubbish he keeps throwing over the fence.

Thank you for giving the basic meaning, it was helpful for understanding the difference between pluck and pluck up.
